# need to replace special characters

Tags: xslt-1.0

Hi I have a part of my xml document as below. In this xsm document I have a special character as “ and &#x201D. I want them to be replaced by “ and ” in my HTML output using XSL.

I am searching for a template or any other alternative method to scan my entire XML document and replace where ever the special characters are found. Right now it is being replaced by some white boxes. Please let me know how do I do it.

```
<para>
            <phrase>2.081</phrase> In creating a vehicle like a restricted purpose company, the British Virgin Islands legislature was clearly concerned that, if such vehicles became widely used, there might be a risk that persons dealing with British Virgin Islands companies generally may have become concerned about the ability of companies to engage in day-to-day transactions. Accordingly, it sought to address these concerns by two slightly different mechanisms. Firstly, all restricted purpose companies were required to include the designation &#x201C;(SPV) Limited&#x201D; in their name, to make sure they were readily identifiable (even without reviewing their constitutional documents). Secondly, restricted purpose companies were made subject to licence fees significantly higher than regular companies to limit their use to appropriate cases.</para>
        <table frame="all" width="100%">
            <title>Comparing restricted purpose companies</title>
            <tgroup cols="3">
                <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="33%"/>
                <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="33%"/>
                <colspec colnum="3" colname="col3" colwidth="33%"/>
                <thead>
```

I also want a method to get the number of `<colspec>` elements below `<tgroup cols="">` (attribute cols should be there). There are also `<tgroup>` elements without the `cols` attribute.

**This is my current XSLT:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">

    <xsl:variable name="ThisDocument" select="document('')"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">


        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="chapter/title"/>
                </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="er:#css" type="text/css" />
            </head>

            <body>


                <xsl:apply-templates/>


                <hr />
                <section class="tr_footnotes">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote" mode="footnote"/>
                </section>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="chapter">
        <section>
            <div class="chapter">
                <a name="BVI-CH-{@num}" />
                <xsl:variable name="cnum">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="starts-with(@num,'0')">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@num,'0')"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable><div class="chapter-title"><span class="chapter-num">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('Chapter ',$cnum,' ')"/>
</span>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div></div>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="chapter/para">
        <div class="para align-right">
            <span class="format-smallcaps">Para</span>.
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Index templates -->
    <xsl:template name="toc" match="chapter/toc">
        <div class="toc">
            <xsl:call-template name="toc-part"></xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="toc-part" match="chapter/toc/toc-part">
        <div class="toc-part">
            <xsl:call-template name="toc-div"></xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="toc-div" match="chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div">
        <table class="toc-div">
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="current()/toc-part/toc-div/*">
                    <xsl:call-template name="toc-item"></xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="toc-item" match="chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item">

        <xsl:variable name="tocpg" >
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('#P',current()/toc-pg/text())"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="tocpgtag" select="translate($tocpg,'.', '-')" />
        <xsl:variable name="chapternumber">
            <!-- Get num attribute of parent node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter[1]/@num"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="itemlevel">
            <xsl:value-of select="$ThisDocument//ntw:nums[@num=$chapternumber]/@word"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="tocitemlevel">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('toc-item-', $itemlevel,'-level')"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>

        <table class="{$tocitemlevel}">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="toc-item-num">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@num"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="toc-title">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/toc-title"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="toc-pg">
                        <a href="{$tocpgtag}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()/toc-pg"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Index Templates Complete -->


    <!-- Paragraph templates -->
    <xsl:template name="section" match="section">
        <!-- Variables-->
        <xsl:variable name ="classname" >
            <!--Get name attribute of current node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('section-',@level)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="chapternumber">
            <!-- Get num attribute of parent node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter[1]/@num"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="sectnum">
            <xsl:number level="any" count="section" format="1"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!--Create a string variable by concat string method  -->
        <xsl:variable name="sectionname">

            <xsl:value-of select="concat('CH-',$chapternumber,'-SEC-0', $sectnum)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- Template Content  -->
        <div class="{$classname}">
            <a name="{$sectionname}"> </a>
            <div class="section-title">
                <span class="section-num">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
                </span>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--<xsl:template name="para"  match="section/para">
    <xsl:variable name="count2">
    <xsl:value-of select="count[child::node()]"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>    
    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$count2 &gt;=1">
                       <div class="para">
            <span class="phrase">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/phrase"/>
            </span>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>              
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$count2 &lt; 1">
                     <span class="phrase">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/phrase"/>
            </span>
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="nr"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>    -->







    <xsl:template name="para" match="section/para">
    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains()">
                        <div class="para">
            <span class="phrase">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/phrase"/>
            </span>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>


    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="phrase" match="phrase">
        <xsl:variable name="phrase">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',text())"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="newphrase" select="translate($phrase,'.','-')"/>

        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newphrase"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </a>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Table Templates  -->
    <xsl:template name ="table" match="table">

        <table style="frame-{current()/@frame} width-{translate(current()/@width,'%','')}"><colgroup></colgroup>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tbody" match="tgroup/tbody">
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/row">
                <xsl:call-template name="row"></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="thead" match="tgroup/thead">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"></xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:for-each select="current()/row">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"></xsl:value-of>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="current()/entry">
                    <xsl:call-template name="headentry"></xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="colspec" match="colspec" >
        <col class="colnum-{current()/@colnum} colname-{current()/@colname} colwidth-{translate(current()/@colwidth,'%','')}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="row" match="tbody/row">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/entry">
                <xsl:call-template name="entry" ></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="entry" match="entry">

    <xsl:variable name="count">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*)"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count &lt; 2">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <td>
            <div class="para align-center">
                <xsl:value-of select="para[position()=1]"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="para">
               <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::node()"></xsl:value-of>
            </div>
        </td>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$count &gt; 1">

        <td>
            <div class="para">

                <!--xsl:value-of select="current()"/-->  
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="headentry" >
        <th>
            <xsl:if test="translate(current()/@namest,'col','') != translate(current()/@nameend,'col','')">
                <xsl:variable name="colspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(current()/@nameend,'col','') - translate(current()/@namest,'col','') + 1" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$colspan"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/para/text()"/>
            </div>
        </th>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Table Templates complete  -->

    <!--List templates -->
    <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="orderedlist">
        <ol class="orderedlist">

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

        </ol>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="orderitem" match="orderlist/item">
        <li class="item">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="item/para">
        <xsl:variable name="itemnumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::item[1]/@num"/>
        </xsl:variable><li class="item">
        <div class="para">
            <span class="item-num">
                <xsl:value-of select="parent::item[1]/@num"/>
            </span>

            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </div></li>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--List templates Complete -->

    <!-- Paragraph templates Complete -->



    <!-- Footnote Templates-->
    <xsl:template match="footnote"><sup>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>footnoteref</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#footnote</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/>

        </a></sup>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="footnote" mode="footnote"><sup>
        <li style="list-style-type:none;indent:0">
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:text>footnote</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:text>#footnoteref</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>tr_ftn</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:number level="any" count="footnote" format="1"/>

            </a>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li></sup>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="footnote/para/uri">
        <a>

        </a>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Footnote Templates Complete -->

    <xsl:template match="content-style">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@format='smallcaps'">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(.),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@format='superscript'">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>



    <!-- Namespace ntw-->
    <ntw:nums num="01" word="first"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="02" word="second"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="03" word="third"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="04" word="forth"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="05" word="fifth"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="06" word="sixth"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="07" word="seventh"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="08" word="eighth"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="09" word="nighth"></ntw:nums>
    <ntw:nums num="10" word="tenth"></ntw:nums>
    <!-- Namespace ntw ends -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think your question is not correct and complete. You say you want to replace " with " (it is the same). Can you please review/edit your question? You also say that now the " are replaced with white bowes (spaces?). Can you also please post your current XSLT?

Comment: Hi Mark, i have updated my xslt, sorry for the confusion i wanted the quotes in a stylish manner like a curved quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am not exactly sure on which place you want to count al the `<colspec>` elements here an explanation of `count()`:

You can use `count(node-set)` (replace node-set with your desired node-set to count) to count all the nodes from where you start it. For example:

**Count all `<colspec>` elements in XML:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//colspec)" />
```

**Count all `<colspec>` elements from the path you are now:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(colspec)" />
```

**Count all `<colspec>` elements from the path you are now below element `<tgroup>`:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(tgroup/colspec)" />
```

Your question about the " is not clear to me. Please keep in mind that HTML and XML have some special characters which you never can display as is in source code. See next:

HTML special characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML
XML special characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Hope it helps you out!